# mvc4 application doesn't load controller from backbone collection url on iis 8.5 after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, backbone.js

This is the first time I have ever tried to publish web application; I'm using IIS 8.5. The application is a Backbone application that retrieves and saved data on SQL Server 2008. I had some issues displaying images and some other files, but I managed to solve it. However, the main collection of the backbone is not loading. I get `GET http://localhost/Edit/GetQuestions 404 (Not Found)` where Edit is the controller. The application works when I run from VSTO 2013 without any issue, but it can't find the MVC4 controller once deployed. Here's my collection

```
App.Collections.Questions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Question,
    url: '../Edit/GetQuestions',    

});
```

I added '..' in the url to test if that works since I had to do that to load images from CSS URL. With or without '..' didn't load the controller.

Here's my route config:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Questions",
                "{Controller}/{action}",
                new { Controller = "Edit", action = "GetQuestions", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                   

            );
```

Can somebody please explain what's going on and how can I fix this? Since this is my first application, I'm still learning and trying to understand how things work. I googled but couldn't find anything that relates to this issue I'm experiencing.

Please let me know if you need me to add anything else to the question. I'm not sure what's useful and what's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to [change web application authentication to use Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941527/change-web-application-authentication-to-use-windows-authentication/24945307#24945307). Turned out, there was no issue with the controller or the url, it was the authentication to the SQL server that wasn't established which couldn't retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//model url
url: 'Edit/GetQuestions' 

 //Router config.
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Edit", action = "GetQuestions", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Sorry I must've forgotten to include it. I already have routes.IgnoreRoute in my RouteConfig. Somehow, relative URL is not resolved and unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Here's something I found similar to the problem I'm having. http://forums.asp.net/t/1972193.aspx?404+Not+Found+when+MVC+deployed+to+IIS+7+5+7600+16385. But I couldn't understand the resolution provided.

Comment: I did what the answer said and yet my application couldn't find the controller and action.

Comment: What url the collection is trying to use? See on console.

Comment: depending on what I changed, it tried to use these: localhost/Edit/Controller/Edit/GetQuestions, localhost/Edit/GetQuestions, localhost/Edit/Edit/GetQuestions. Edit after the localhost is the application name and the second Edit is the controller name. I know it's bit confusing and not a good name which I'm gonna change once this problem is resolved.

Comment: One thing I just noticed in RequestURL is that in the dev machine (the one that's working properly) has it set to http://localhost:65004/Edit/GetQuestions, whereas the RequestURL the deployed application is requesting is: http://localhost/Edit/GetQuestions. So, how can I make this app look at the correct directory?