# change web application authentication to use Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api, iis-8.5

I'm trying to publish my web application on IIS 8.5, but I'm getting this error when the application tries to retrieve data from the SQL Server 2008.

InnerException: {Message:An error has occurred., ExceptionMessage:Login failed for user 'domainname\WES-JXC2J02$'.,…}
ExceptionMessage: "Login failed for user 'domainname\WES-JXC2J02$'."

The SQL Server doesn't have WES-JXC2J02$ listed as the authorized user because it's my dev machine name. If I try to add the machine name as user in SQL Server it gives me an error because there's no such user in the domain. I want to use Windows Authentication which is set to enable in IIS. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: So it published successfully?

Comment: @MikeCheel It published successfully and I can even see the Index page. It is a backbone application, so when I go to the link where it should display a table with data, I get that error. Other than that, it displays everything fine.

Comment: I just don't understand why it's trying to login as domain\machinename. Any idea?

Comment: I was doing something recently that is similar (or at least reminds me of what you are doing). I was trying to make a call from my browser to my web api and the web api was making a call to our tfs server. The problem was that my choices are I would need to enable delegation on my web api server (via AD) or I would have to roll my own proxy to get the credentials to tfs. Without me doing one of those it was forwarding my machine credentials to the server (much like you are describing). I ended up moving my web api to the tfs server to fix it (my third option).

Comment: Also I *think* when you use Network Service as your app pool account it wants to authenticate with the machine name. I'm not 100% on that one.

Comment: @MikeCheel So, what should I do? What's the easiest way to solve this. Since the web application is not going to be on the Internet, security is not really my issue currently.

Comment: Without taking a look at the actual details of your app I couldn't really say. Typically I don't give the typical app user direct permissions to the database and use role based or claims based security with a server account. Sorry I cannot be more helpful.

Comment: @MikeCheel Thank you. At least you showed me a path to look in and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, as @MikeCheel said, it was forwarding my machine credentials to the SQL Server to retrieve the data from the database. Turned out, I needed to create a new login in SQL Server with limited access, then add the user id and password in the connectionString. I learnt it the hard way that SQL Server must have SQL and Windows Authentication enabled. Once that was configured, connection was setup and the data displayed properly.